# I want to have my pl/pgsql script output to the screen

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I have the following script that I want output to the screen from.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION randomnametest() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM my_table LOOP
        SELECT levenshtein('mystring',lower('rec.Name')) ORDER BY levenshtein;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to get the output of the levenshein() function in a table along with the rec.Name. How would I do that? Also, it is giving me an error about the line where I call levenshtein(), saying that I should use perform instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* you want the output from a plpgsql function like the title says:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION randomnametest(_mystring text)
  RETURNS TABLE (l_dist int, name text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT levenshtein(_mystring, lower(t.name)), t.name
    FROM   my_table t
    ORDER  BY 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Declare the table with [`RETURNS TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).
- Use [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to return records from the function.
- Avoid naming conflicts between column names and `OUT` parameters (from the `RETURNS TABLE` clause) by table-qualifying column names in queries. `OUT` parameters are visible everywhere in the function body.
- I made the string to compare to a parameter to the function to make this more useful.

There are other ways, but this is the most effective for the task. You need PostgreSQL 8.4 or later.

For a one-time use I would consider to just use a plain query (= function body without the `RETURN QUERY` above).

Comment: I can't do a for loop outside of a function.

Comment: Nevermind, I just noticed that your solution does not require a for loop.

Comment: I have a problem, the column name is Name and not name, how do I do capitals?

Comment: @alfonzo1955: [PostgreSQL identifiers are case-insensitive](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Enclose `"Name"` in double-quotes to preserve camel-case (and other illegal strings) as name. I would advise *never* to use identifiers that have to be double-quoted, i.e. no [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and only lower case. Makes your life easier.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you want to `insert` the function's return value and the `rec.name` into a different table. Here is what you can do (`create` the table `new_tab` first)-

```
SELECT levenshtein('mystring',lower(rec.Name)) AS L_val;
INSERT INTO new_tab (L_val, rec.name);
```

The usage above is demonstrated below.

I guess, you can use `RAISE INFO 'This is %', rec.name;` to view the values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION randomnametest() RETURNS integer AS $$

DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM my_table LOOP
        SELECT levenshtein('mystring',lower(rec.Name))
         AS L_val;

       RAISE INFO '%   -   %', L_val, rec.name; 
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Note**- the `FROM` clause is optional in case you select from a function in a select like `netxval(sequence_name)` and don't have any actual table to select from i.e. like `SELECT nextval(sequence_name) AS next_value;`, in Oracle terms it would be `SELECT sequence_name.nextval FROM dual;` or `SELECT function() FROM dual;`. There is no `dual` in `postgreSQL`.

I also think that the `ORDER BY` is not necessary since my assumption would be that your function `levenshtein()` will most likely return only one value at any point of time, and hence wouldn't have enough data to `ORDER`.

Comment: I don't want to store it in a different table just yet. I want to see the output.

Comment: You can use `dbms_output.put_line` inside the function to see the output, but I don't recommend it. Instead use the PLSQL block that I updated in the answer to see the values. See the updated answer.

Comment: What is the function of the slash on the last line?

Comment: `/` executes the PLSQL block in SQL Prompt. You can save the PLSQL block (including the `/`) on a script name it as `myplsql.sql` and then run it from SQL prompt as `SQL> @myplsql.sql`.

Comment: I think question is for PostgreSQL, not ORACLE.

Comment: Don't single-quote the column. In the query `FROM` is missing. The function is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: The OP wanted to "PRINT" or VIEW the results and that's what I answered. I know its a simple function with overtly written code, but any one can optimize that.

Comment: @Annjawn: If you [`@`-reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/169168) (like I do, but you would be notified anyway because we are posting under your post) I will be notified about your answer. I found this by chance. Basically neither of your answers work as of now. Another possible reaction would be to fix them.

Comment: Dear Mr @ErwinBrandstetter- Thanks for pointing out the error. I have fixed it. Also, i think the `FROM` clause is optional if you select from a function in postgres (not in Oracle). What if there is no table to select from (in Oracle we use `dual`). So to your earlier point- I guess I don't need `FROM` in my query.